# Javascript event-listener not working when trying to link to another page

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection, event-listener

I'm currently trying to display an individual.html page based off what the user clicks on a products.html page. For example, clicking on product1 would show the individual page for product1 and clicking on product2 would show the individual page for product2 etc...

I currently have a UI class in my app.js file which holds the logic for displaying information.
There is a function in there called `displayIndividualProject()` which has an event listener that says, "If a card is clicked (`if (event.target.classList.contains('img-container'))`), then inject this HTML structure into the individual.html" page. However, after I click on it, it's not injecting the sequence.

Also, `displayIndividualProduct` is meant for the individual.html page while `displayProducts` is meant for the product.html page.

Here is what part of my UI class looks like:

```
const individualProductsDOM = document.querySelector('.single-product');

class UI{
       displayIndividualProduct(){
    
            document.addEventListener("click", event => {
                if (event.target.classList.contains('img-container'))
                    individualProductsDOM.innerHTML = 
            
                    `
                    <div class='section-title'>
                    <h2>${product.title}</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class='indi-img-container'>
                      <img src=${product.image} data-id='${product.id} alt="">
                      
        

                  </div>
                  <div class="product-footer">
                      <h3>Estimated Cost: $ <span class='item-total'>0</span></h3>
                      <button class='bag-btn-2' data-id='${product.id}'>
                          <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>
                          add to cart
                      </button> 
                  </div>
                    `
    
            })
    
            individualProductsDOM.innerHTML += `injected`;
    
            
        }

displayProducts(products){
    let result = '';
    products.forEach(product => {
        result += `
        
            <article class="product" data-id='${product.id}'>
                    <div class='img-container'>
                    <a href='/individual.html'>  
                        <img src=${product.image} alt="product" class='product-img' data-id='${product.id}'>
                        
                        <button class='bag-btn' data-id='${product.id}'>
                            <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>
                            add to cart
                        </button> 
                        </a>
                    </div>
                
                <h3>${product.title}</h3>
                <h4>$${product.price}/roll</h4>
                
            </article>  
        

         `
    
    });

    //insert the products into the productsDOM
    productsDOM.innerHTML = result; 
}


}
```

and this is being called at the bottom of my JS through `ui.displayIndividualProduct();`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const ui = new UI();
    const products = new Products();

    // setup app
    ui.setupAPP();


    //get all products
    products.getProducts().then(products => {
        //first display, then save, and then connect the add cart buttons
        ui.displayProducts(products);
        Storage.saveProducts(products);
    }).then( () => {
        ui.getBagButtons();
    });

    ui.displayIndividualProduct();



});
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are moving from page to page (which is what you state in the first part of your question). It sounds like a click causes the contents of the current page to change. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I updated to clarify what my `displayProducts` would look like. Basically, I wrap my cards in an anchor tag, and the desired result is when I click it, for it to be redirected to a specialized individual.html page.